# GitHub Commit Gate-Keeper

Tags: github, git-commit

Do we have any way to Gate-Keep our organisation's GitHub Commits? I want to ensure none of our developer's GitHub commits to public repository is exposing any specific strings/Keys.

So a Gatekeeper scripts which parses through the Commits made by our developers and forbids a commit in case it exposes a particular string. I am aware Private repository is the obvious solution but we should have restriction on public repository 
 too.

Answer (score -1):

You might consider putting in place a [GitHub Action workflow](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-workflow-with-github-actions), similar to [this repository](https://github.com/actions/vulnerability-scan/blob/master/.github/main.workflow) in order to scan the content of a pushed commit (using one of the [security scanners](https://geekflare.com/github-credentials-scanner/)).

And, as an action, you could reset the branch to the previous commit, effectively cancelling what has just been pushed.

If the action does not detect any sensitive data, you can in turn push the commit to a [protected branch](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-protected-branches), which acts as the blessed content from which developers can pull.